# Select latest history record from db

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `order_history` which contain record of all actions that i perform on order like `confirm order`, `attempted order`, `reject order` or `revert order`.

When an employee mark order as `attempt` it create a history and after some time admin `revert` that order back to its original place (it also create history). After that, some other employee mark same order as `attempt`.

**Problem**

Now, `history` table has 2 records of same order for attempted. and i want to pick only latest `attempted` history because the previous action was reverted.

**DB Structure**

```
|history_id |order_id | date_added   |user_id | action_id|
|-----------|---------|--------------|--------|----------|
| 13        | 444     | 2018/07/06   |   9    |2         |
| 12        | 555     | 2018/07/05   |   7    |2         |
| 11        | 444     | 2018/07/05   |   2    |3         |
| 10        | 555     | 2018/07/05   |   2    |3         |
| 9         | 555     | 2018/07/05   |   4    |2         |
| 8         | 444     | 2018/07/04   |   1    |2         |
```

Where `user_id` = Employee and action_id `2 for attempt` and `3 for revert back` ,When order is attempted then revert and then again attempted by other employee, my query duplicate the order in both employee A and B but it should show in latest employee account.

**MY Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(oh.order_id) AS total_attempted,
       oh.user_id
FROM `order_history` oh 
WHERE oh.action_id = '2'
GROUP BY oh.user_id
```

**Result**

This query display `order ID : 555` to both users `user_id: 4 and 7` but order 555 should be only displayed for user 7.

**Expected Output**

```
|history_id |order_id | date_added   |user_id | action_id|
|-----------|---------|--------------|--------|----------|
| 13        | 444     | 2018/07/06   |   9    |2         |
| 12        | 555     | 2018/07/05   |   7    |2         |
```

PS: *All action on order 555 was performed on same date*

Lemme know if more details required.

Comment: Can you post your expected output ?

Comment: updated ...please check

Comment: I am not clear what you want here. I get that you want to ignore reverted orders but what if an order has been confirmed of rejected? Or do you simply want those whose current status is attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output does not tally with your attempted code. If you want only the latest attempt then you need to look at attempts AND reversions.

```
drop table if exists oh;
create table oh (history_id int,order_id int,date_added varchar(100),user_id int,action_id int);
insert into oh (history_id ,order_id,date_added,user_id,action_id) values(13,444,"2018/07/06",9,2);
insert into oh (history_id ,order_id,date_added,user_id,action_id) values(12,555,"2018/07/05",7,2);
insert into oh (history_id ,order_id,date_added,user_id,action_id) values(11,444,"2018/07/05",2,3);
insert into oh (history_id ,order_id,date_added,user_id,action_id) values(10,555,"2018/07/05",2,3);
insert into oh (history_id ,order_id,date_added,user_id,action_id) values(9,555,"2018/07/05",4,2);
insert into oh (history_id ,order_id,date_added,user_id,action_id) values(8,444,"2018/07/04",1,2);
insert into oh values(7,333,"2018/07/04",1,3),(6,333,"2018/07/04",1,2),
(5,222,"2018/07/04",1,2),(4,222,"2018/07/04",2,2),
(3,111,"2018/07/04",1,2);
```

The sub query s finds the latest action based on history_id (I have assumed this indicates the order of events)

This code lists the latest attempts

```
select * from
(
select *
from   oh 
where  action_id in (2,3) and 
         history_id = (select max(history_id) from oh oh1 where oh1.order_id = oh.order_id)
) s
where s.action_id = 2;

+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+
| history_id | order_id | date_added | user_id | action_id |
+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+
|         13 |      444 | 2018/07/06 |       9 |         2 |
|         12 |      555 | 2018/07/05 |       7 |         2 |
|          5 |      222 | 2018/07/04 |       1 |         2 |
|          3 |      111 | 2018/07/04 |       1 |         2 |
+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

This code counts the number of attempts (excluding reversions by user)

```
select user_id,count(*) attempts
from
(
select *
from   oh 
where  action_id in (2,3) and 
         history_id = (select max(history_id) from oh oh1 where oh1.order_id = oh.order_id)
) s
where s.action_id = 2
group by user_id;

+---------+----------+
| user_id | attempts |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        2 |
|       7 |        1 |
|       9 |        1 |
+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```